# Product topology on $R^\omega$ and Banach Spaces

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Question 1: Does there exist norm on $R^\omega$ such that topology is same as product topology?

Question 2: Does there exist norm on $R^\omega$ such that corresponding normed space is Banach and topology is same as product topology?

Comment: What is $R^\omega$ ?

Comment: @AndréS. countable product of $R$

Answer (score 1):

The product topology on $\mathbb R^\omega$ is the initial topology with respect to the projections $\pi_n$ defined by $x\mapsto x_n$. Any neighbourhood $U$ of $0$ thus contains a set of the form $\bigcap\limits_{n\in E} \pi_n^{-1}((-r_n,r_n))$ for a finite set $E$ and some $r_n>0$. Hence $U$ contains huge (co-finite dimensional) subspaces whereas balls with respect to a norm cannot contain non-trivial subspaces.

Comment: How $U$ contains subspace? And what does co-finite dimensional means?

Comment: Co-finite dimensional means that $W  / V$ is finite-dimensional if $V$ is a subspace of $W$.  Since $E$ is finite, we have $V \subset U$ for $V = \prod_{i \in \omega} A_i$, where $A_i = \mathbb{R}$ if $i \notin E$ and $A_i = \{0\}$ if $i \in \omega$. Note that $V$ is a 'huge' subspace and $\rm{dim}(\mathbb{R}^\omega / V)  = |E|$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fact, that $[0,1]^\omega$ is not sequentially-compact but by Tychonoff's theorem compact, to see that $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ with the product-topology is not-metrizable.

Comment: It is metrisable space hence your argument has to be wrong.

Comment: What is $\omega$? The cardinality of all countable ordinal numbers? Or the set of all finite ordinals? In the last case, we have just $\mathbb{R}^\omega \cong \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$. This is a Frechet-space, i.e. complete, separable locally convex topological vector space. In order to see that this is not a Banach-space, note that normable implies that there exists a convex bounded neighborhood $U$ of $0$. Here 'bounded' is defined as follows: For every neighborhood $V$ of $0$  there exists $s>0$ such that $U \subset t V$ for every $t >s$.

Comment: sorry unfamiliar with these notion. Is there some other way to prove it. It meant by last one.

Comment: If your space is normable and $V$ is any neighborhood of $0$, then $B_\varepsilon(0) \subset V$. Taking $U= B_1(0)$, we see that $U \subset t V$ for all $t > \varepsilon^{-1}$. That is a simple observation. Thus, in any normable space we have this property: There exists an open neighborhood $U$ of $0$ with the following property: For any neighborhood $V$ of $0$ there is an $s>0$ such that $U \subset t V$ for all $t > s$.

Comment: In our example, taking any open neigbhorhood $U$ of $0$, w.l.o.g. $U =  \bigcap_{i \in I} \pi_i^{-1}(U_i)$, where $I$ is finite, we can define $V= \pi_j^{-1}((0,1))$ for some $j \notin I$. Then $U \not \subset t V$ forall $t>0$. Therefore, this space is not normable.